# Ruby on Rails add info to .find result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, find

Please bear in mind that I'm totally new to Rails when answering this.My question is as follow:

I have an Array that is result of a .find query. This Array is passed to view and each item is shown. BUT, before passing it I need to add info to each of the Array elements.
If each element was an Array I could use <<, if it was a hash I could use .merge, but since I have no idea whatsoever of what it is I don't know how I can add the info.....

Hope you can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, your comment clears it up a bit. When you do `User.find(n)` you get back a `user` object. If you do something like `User.find(1, 2, 3)` then you get an array of `user` objects. So adding to this dynamically is probably not an ideal solution.

But here's one hacky way to do it

```
users = User.find(1, 2, 3)
modified_users = users.map { |user| Array(user) << "some value tacked on" }
```

This will convert your `user` object to an array and then append a value to it. Not recommended but it will do what you're asking for.

Comment: that is exactly what I'm trying to figure out. What does find returns? It's not an Array, neither a Hash. It's something else that I don't know how to add info......

Comment: I though it wouldn't be recommended, but I'm just out of time to fix everything to make it work with a better way. Thank you!!!

Comment: @elithin: the object returned from `find` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. It (generally) behaves like an Array of model instances.

Comment: @zetetic Hrmm...I just did `User.find(1, 2, 3).class` and it says `Array`.

Comment: @Dty: I stand corrected. You'll note, though, that `User.where(:id=>[1,2,3])` returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. I must have misremembered.

Comment: @zetetic yeah I usually don't know which is which. That's why I used rails console to check :)

Comment: my query is a find_by_id, so it'll return only one object.IS there a way to "concatenate" info to this object? Like << to Array and merge to Hash?

Comment: Pretty much the same as what I showed in my answer without the `.map`. Just do `Array(User.find_by_id(1)) << "some value"`

Comment: If you only have one object, why are you passing it to the view as an Array?

Comment: because I process the item and add to an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can findout what are they...just  `puts results.class`

If you don't want to mess with your objects in the array you could make an array or hash having your added information.

```
results.map do |r|
  Hash[result: r, info: "your information here"]
end
```

Comment: If it's result of a .find query it's not an array neither a hash. what is it? I don't care to mess with the array.

Comment: Ohhh, you mean ActiveRecord find method? If so, it's supposed to return one object of that class. So if you are doing User.find(1), it return a user object with the id=1 in your database. You can then do user.name = "something". Maybe you should provide your call to find method

Comment: The problem was, the info I wanted to add was not a field of, say, User, so I couldn't add to a specific field, for example user.name +"info". I've solved it in not a pretty nor recommended way, as said by Dty, but works.... Thank you for helping. By the way, if you know of a better simple alternative I would be happy to hear.